# Hide Item onScroll React

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to hide an item when a user scrolls *within* a div. The Card component shown is a scrollable component. When the user scrolls within it I want to hide an item. What is the best way to go about this? I'm getting the error: *Too many re-renders*. Note: Partial code shown

```
const [scrolling, setScrolling] = useState(false);
    const handleScroll = (e) => {
      setScrolling(true);
    };
    
    return (
      <Card onScroll={handleScroll}>
        {scrolling ? null :  <p> hide me on scroll </p>}
      </Card>
    );
```

Comment: How does the `scrolling` state ever get set back to `false`? (Also you could wrap the setState in an `if`, there's no point re-setting the state to true if it's already set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something you could do is move the `scrolling ? null : ...` outside of the return and just keep it a variable.

Like this:

```
const [scrolling, setScrolling] = useState(false);
const handleScroll = (e) => {
  setScrolling(true);
};

const item = scrolling ? null :  <p> hide me on scroll </p>
    
return (
  <Card onScroll={handleScroll}>
    {item}
  </Card>
);
```

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thanks!